# Graph the current duration in second

Tags: grafana, graphite

I would like to display the total duration in seconds from the beginning of the range to the end.

The graph would have the total duration in seconds as Y axis and the time as X axis.

It would start from 0s to 3600s for a range of one hour.

I manage to graph it based on a Graphite series however it is not correct when the range is too wide. I guess it is related to the cleaning of the data after some time.
[image: total duration over time]

Comment: It might be helpful to see what functions you're currently using - maybe there's a way to fix that up? If you find it works less well zoomed out further, do have a go at using the consolidateBy function - 3 years supporting Graphite and that's the number two reason for data to be displayed weirdly :) (the number one only applies to Hosted Graphite, but if you're using HG check out data views, or drop a mail to support and I'll take a look!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graphite includes a function called [timeFunction](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.timeFunction) which just returns the timestamp for every point in the graph, at an interval you choose. Combined with the [offsetToZero](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.offsetToZero) function, you can draw a line that [counts up in standard time increments and starts at 0 regardless of the duration of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSMRP.png). It looks like this:

```
offsetToZero(timeFunction('duration', 60))
```

I tested this up to 90 days and at various maxdataPoint values and it seems to work fine. 60s is the default interval for timeFunction, but you can use whatever you like depending on what you think would be a good interval for your dashboard.

If you have a different version of Graphite and you still see the values look strange at different zoom levels, try adding [consolidateBy(max)](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.consolidateBy) to make sure that if the data points are being consolidated, the highest value is used instead of the average. You might also consolidateBy(min) - Graphite datapoints represent the following period of time instead of the previous, so the first datapoint might be mathematically more correct, depending on your implementation.

(NB: Consolidation of datapoints happens because Grafana sends a maxDataPoints value with its requests to Grafana so that Graphite doesn't return more datapoints that the graph can display.)

Comment: it works well, thanks ! However when I used as input in another serie in `asPercent` and I got errors while the previous solution I had was working (with an incorrect total still). Any idea why?

Comment: At a guess, the series generated by time and your own series don't have matching intervals. The asPercent function isn't capable of comparing datapoints with different timestamps, and the time function generates it's own timestamps regardless of the actual storage scheme. You might be able to get past that by changing the interval of the time function to match your own storage scheme at the timeframe you're most likely to be viewing. If you're using Grafana to view it, you can use a template variable to select different intervals from a list you provide.

Comment: I used `divideSeries` instead of `asPercent` and it works well know ! Thanks a lot for your help!